# Do both of these reducers get called on every action dispatch?

Tags: swift, redux, reducers

```swift
func appStateReducer(state: AppState, action: Action) -> AppState {
  var state = state
  state.moviesState = moviesStateReducer(state: state.moviesState, action: 
    action)
  state.peoplesState = peoplesStateReducer(state: state.peoplesState, 
  action: action)
  return state
}
```

e.g. would:

```
store.dispatch(action: MoviesActions.RemoveFromWishlist(movie: movie))
```

end up calling both the `moviesState` & `peoplesState` reducer? 
If so, any reason why one wouldn't put a conditional in to only call one reducer per action?

Source:

https://github.com/Dimillian/MovieSwiftUI/blob/master/MovieSwift/Shared/flux/reducers/AppReducer.swift

Higher level directory source:

https://github.com/Dimillian/MovieSwiftUI/tree/52e852fc3da2524fd784374727e747eaba8497b6/MovieSwift/Shared/flux

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, yes, all the reducer functions will be called on every action. According to the [docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance/#wont-calling-all-my-reducers-for-each-action-be-slow), that being a performance hindrance is highly unlikely. Usually, only one reducer does the state update, and all the other reducers just run through their `switch` statements, so the time complexity scales with the amount of `actions` you have, which is unlikely to reach the numbers high enough to take significant time (`10^7` or so).

You can, however, use libraries like `redux-ignore` to make reducers ignore specific actions and/or `reduxr-scoped-reducer` to make reducers only respond to specific actions.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Might the primary reason for calling all substate reducers on every action be the following: Calling all substate reducer functions is 'safer' because these states are structs (value types in swift), and any assignment [required on state change] means new copy [aligns with immutable state redux philosophy], so best to get a new substate structs from 1 source: the substate reducer's `return state`. And all reducers have a required action param, so must pass in something [even an action it wont respond to, and this would be blocked by an 'ignore specific actions' conditional].

Comment: Well, if by "ignoring" you mean skipping calling some reducer functions entirely, then that might be a concern, yes. However, if the reducer just returns the copy of the previous state immediately (hence "ignoring" the action) without doing any further checks, then that shouldn't be an issue. `redux-ignore` will make sure that nothing goes wrong. Although, as I said, there's no need to be concerned about calling all the reducers on dispatch. That behavior takes away many headaches altogether.